# Is there an Idiom where a person praises another to get his work done?

Tags: idioms

Is there a Idiom where a person praises another to get his work done ?

This usually happens in my work environment. Few execs praise my work just to dump it over me and get their job done.

**-- Proposed edit:**

Is there an idiom where a person praises another for getting his work done?

The following is what usually happens in my work environment: A few execs praise my work, and call the job done. Just in time for an exec to dump some more trash on me, to get his own work done.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like either the phrase 'to dangle a carrot' where by you are incentivised to do something by receiving something good, in this case the carrot is the praise you are given. It could also be 'sweet talk' if it is insincere praise.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be indelicate, but this is what is described as "blowing sunshine up someone's ass." It means dishing out insincere flattery to achieve a desired result. In the workplace, that means if the one praising does the sunshine thing enough, the target will work harder. It's easily seen through, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a ***pep talk*** - this is a term that's often used derisively for the poor quality of the enthusiasm engendered.  "Pep" can only be sarcastic in an office environment:  "Oh great, here comes another fly-by pep talk from the VP. I'll be sure to work extra hard now."

> [**pep talk**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pep%20talk) -
>
> a short speech that is given to encourage someone to work harder, to feel more confident and enthusiastic, etc.

There are times when the term isn't used derisively or ironically, but if you used it in the context you describe, no one is going to think either your connotation or the manger delivering the pep talk was earnest.

Answer (score 0):

Give credit where credit is due.

Provide positive feedback.

Acknowledge someone's efforts OR hard work.