# What is one word/phrase for pretending to like something while it’s not good?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

For example, a guy shows his friend something he’s written, and she smiles awkwardly and praises him, and gives him positive comments, while the writing itself isn’t good anyway. How do you describe the friend’s reaction? Out of sympathy? Or is there a better word for it?

Thanks!

Comment: What's her motive for giving the praise? Is she genuinely trying to encourage him or just trying to avoid looking negative?

Comment: There's a question about praising someone insincerely because you want something, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267695/is-there-an-idiom-where-a-person-praises-another-to-get-his-work-done), but I guess this is different?

Comment: Does *white lie* float your boat?  If not, perhaps explain why not and what particular nuances you are trying to express.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is clear and you illustrate it with an example circumstance. Although you do not give us any of your own research on the topic (such as possible words or phrases that you do not find quite right, so you want advice), you are a newcomer and should be encouraged, not downvoted without explanation. I have compensated for that. Nevertheless please look at the site help/guide to see what makes a good question

Comment: As KillingTime suggests, the term depends on the speaker's motives, where the untruth might be variously described as _being polite_ or _flattery_ to _insincerity_ or even _self-protection_. Depending on the culture, it might even be done out of _respect_. Please [edit] your question to describe how the speaker felt.

Comment: I answered this question because it is entirely clear what is being asked. However, I can see there was a hint of obscurity in writing about the "person", which clearly referred to the "friend", so I have edited the question as a prelude to voting for reopening. Also, it is discourteous to newcomers to treat them so dismissively; this is behaviour that goes against the site recommendation about how to treat newcomers.

Comment: @Anton - I'm not sure whether the question should be reopened, since there isn't more information about the word's connotation, although I do appreciate the effort that the OP put into at least providing general context. May I ask what was 'dismissive' about the community's reaction? All the comments seem to be constructive.

Comment: @Heartspring you are right about the comments, which in this and many similar other instances are indeed constructive. On the other hand  I think it dismissive to close a question, for then it receives no more attention from the whole community, being visible only to certain people. This is hardly the welcoming and mentoring greeting that should be accorded to newcomers.

Comment: The objects of these bogus sentiments should
"be advised that all flatterers live at the expense of those who listen to them," which is the moral of La Fontaine's fable of The Crow and the Fox.

Comment: @Anton - so you think that questions that need improvement should not be closed if they are from newcomers? A better policy would be, in my opinion, to give the OP more guidance than just the emotionless, unspecialized close message. Perhaps we could give them some tips/suggestions on how to get the question reopened in a manner specifically tailored to them. But I have to say, I disagree with the point that such questions should be left open.

Comment: @Heartspring We should really go to meta to continue this but as a final note I cannot argue that all newcomer questions should be kept open. I argue that in this case the question was so clear that it should have been given a little latitude. I certainly agree with you that the site’s formulaic reason for closure is inadequate; when voting for closure I try to remember to give a personal reason for doing so, in the hope that the new OP will not be discouraged for ever.

Answer (score 1):

She is **feigning delight** at his efforts.

The phrase may be found in many google ngram results. Here is one:

> [Stevens' Handbook of Experimental Psychology p251](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Stevens_Handbook_of_Experimental_Psychol/LzBMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22feign+delight%22&pg=PA251&printsec=frontcover)
> "say you see a friend receive a gift that you know does not suit him or her; the person may feign delight despite an underlying disappointment"

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feign)
> *feign*
> to pretend to have a particular feeling, problem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that she is **sugarcoating** things. [Cambridge defines "sugarcoat" as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sugarcoat)

> to make something seem more positive or pleasant than it really is

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> She is humoring/humouring him.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humour) has

> **humour**
> to do what someone wants so that they do not become annoyed or upset

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humor) has

> **humor**
> to soothe or content (someone) by indulgence : to comply with the temperament or inclinations of